# SQL Using Not Between by defining a range in an another unrelated table

Tags: sql

I have a table-A with an ID field. Table-A has 50 rows. 
Id field has values 1..2..3...50.
Table-B has  fields: RangeFrom, RangeTo.
Table-B has 2 rows.
Values for Row 1 are RangeFrom = 8 , RangeTo=12.
Values for Row 2 are: RangeFrom=25, RangeTo = 30.

I am trying to accomplish :

```
Select * from Table-A where Table-A ID Not Between Table-B RangeFrom And RangeTo.
```

The result should show me all IDs except 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30.
Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: Whatr RDBMS are you using i.e. SQL Server, Oracle etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is right the way you have phrased the query.  Table B has two rows.  Something say 9 is in the range for the first row.  It is not in the range of the second row.

What you want is to find the rows that match 0 rows instead.  You can do this with a left outer join:

```
Select a.*
from Table-A a left outer join
     Table-B b
     on a.ID Between b.RangeFrom And b.RangeTo
where b.rangeFrom is NULL;
```

Comment: I am going to give it a try and let you know. Though one question -Table B has no ID field. When you do a join do you not  need a corresponding field in the other tables? Please excuse me for my basic knowledge on SQL queries. And yeah..thanks for responding.

Comment: @Shankar . . . "join" is a general term for forming a subset of the cartesian product of two tables.  Some joins use ids, some do not.  Equi-joins have an equality relationship -- which is good for performance.  This is an example of a non-equijoin.

Comment: This didn't work out. It returns no data. However, if I change the query to where b.rangeFrom is NOT NULL then 8, 9, 10, 11, 12  is eliminated but 25...30 still shows up.

Comment: @Shankar . . . Try it with the condition:  `a.ID Between b.RangeFrom And b.RangeTo`.

Comment: Select a.*
from Table-A a left outer join
     Table-B b
     on a.ID Between b.RangeFrom And b.RangeTo
where b.rangeFrom is NULL =========== returns no data

When changed to NOT NULL returns 8..12 eliminated but not 25...

Comment: @Shankar . . . Something is wrong.  The current version should return the ids in a that match no ranges in b.  Do you think you could put the example on SQL Fiddle?